# Ansible with_fileglob is skipping

Tags: ansible

I am putting together an Ansible Playbook designed to build webservers. However I am stuck when trying to use `with_fileglob` because Ansible keeps reporting that it's skipping the copy of nginx vhost files.

My script looks like this:

```
 - name: Nginx | Copy vhost files
   copy: src={{ item }} dest=/etc/nginx/sites-available owner=root group=root  mode=600
   with_fileglob:
     - "{{ templates_dir }}/nginx/sites-available/*"  
   notify
   - nginx-restart:
```

`{{ templates }}` has been defined elsewhere as *roles/common/templates*. In this directory I have a file called *webserver1* that I'm hoping Ansible will copy into `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`

I have found other people discussing this issue but no responses have helped me solve this problem. Why would Ansible be skipping files?

Edit: I should point out that I want to use `with_fileglob` (rather than straight copy) as I want to iterate over other virtual hosts in the future.

Comment: OK, it seems that I can only use absolute URLs here. Maybe it's because I am using through Vagrant using vagrant provision but this is not ideal. I thought I could use variables that include the absolute URLs but it seems it has to be static in order to work.

Comment: OK, I found the problem. It seems I grabbed used some old examples when creating variables. I was using:  `templates_dir: src="{{ base_dir }}/roles/common/templates"` when I should have been using  ` templates_dir: "{{ base_dir }}/roles/common/templates"`

Answer (score 15):

Look at http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-fileglobs, Note 1:

> When using a relative path with with_fileglob in a role, Ansible resolves the path relative  to the **roles//files** directory.

So to access a file in the templates directory, you can start the relative path with **../templates**

Comment: you could also move the files from the ```templates``` directory into the ```files``` directory.

Comment: There are some magic variables such as `playbook_dir` and `role_path`. It would be better to use them instead of `../` because roles quite often might be installed or kept somewhere else. Don't rely on structure of only one project